# Pasar datos desde una función a una petición GET

Tags: python, python-3.x

¿Cómo hago para pasar datos a una URL desde una función?

Cuando la ejecuto directamente me funciona perfecta.

```
response = requests.get('http://api.open-notify.org/iss-pass.json?lat=66115&lon=15198') # Valores random
```

Pero si quiero pasarle los datos desde una función ya no se cómo, ¿me podeis ayudar? He probado:

```
def funcion(lat,lon):
    response = requests.get('http://api.open-notify.org/iss-pass.json?lat='+lat+'&lon='+lon) #ERROR

funcion(66115,15198) #Valores inventados
```

También he probado poner la url:

```
response = requests.get('http://api.open-notify.org/iss-pass.json?lat=lat&lon=lon') #ERROR

response = requests.get('http://api.open-notify.org/iss-pass.json?lat=',lat,'&lon='lon) #ERROR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu idea de concatenarlas como parte de la URL podría funcionar, pero ya que los parámetros de la función no son cadenas sino números, debes convertirlos en cadena. Es decir algo como esto:

```
response = requests.get('http://api.open-notify.org/iss-pass.json?lat='
                        +str(lat) + '&lon=' + str(lon))
```

Sin embargo esa no es la mejor forma. En este caso funcionaría, pero en otros casos en los que los parámetros pudieran ser cadenas y éstas pudieran contener caracteres no válidos (como espacios, o unicode), este método daría lugar a URLs inválidas.

Es mejor dejar que la biblioteca `requests` construya para tí una URL válida. Para ello basta que le pases a `.get()` un parámetro llamado `params` que ha de ser un diccionario cuyas claves y valores se usarán en la parte query de la URL. Tú sólo tienes que pasarle la base de la URL (lo que había hasta el `?`).

Es decir:

```
def funcion(lat,lon):
    params = { "lat": lat,  "lon": lon }
    response = requests.get('http://api.open-notify.org/iss-pass.json', 
                             params=params)
```